# Change meta information for link to page

Tags: pages

I recently created a new page in Wordpress, using the Divi template, and then decided to send a link to that page to one of my coworkers over MS Teams.

MS Teams seems to look up meta information about the page and then presents the link in the following way:

```
Page-Name | Website-Name
A post from vic on Website-Name provided by:
https://www.mycompany.com

www.mycompany.com
```

In particular, I'm bothered by the line "A post from..." and the line after that.

What is creating this information, is it the template (Divi) or is it Wordpress Core and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The Yoast SEO plugin (free version) lets you change this information pretty handily. Divi does have the ability to alter the SEO meta information also. This article is pretty good overview: https://divicake.com/blog/getting-started-with-divi-theme-options-seo-tab/